# How to show an image for the ajax interval

Tags: php, ajax, image, intervals

I am developing an ajax based web site in which , I would like to show an image ( like progress bar ) for the ajax loading time . I mean , would like to show an image just after the user click on a div and need to dis appear it after getting the result from the ajax page. How can I do that...? Thanks in advance.

This is the code sample

```
$.ajax({
            dataType:'json',
            type:"POST",
            url:"ajaxJobs.php",
            data:{

                p:$(this).attr('id')
            },
            success:function(result){

            }
        });
```

Comment: Add the image before $.ajax(), and remove it as first step inside success().

Comment: go here download the code http://www.atwebresults.com/php_ajax_image_upload/ , it will explain how to use it as-well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this

```
<img id="loading" src="path/to/loading/img" />
<script>
$.ajax({
        dataType:'json',
        type:"POST",
        url:"ajaxJobs.php",
        data:{

            p:$(this).attr('id')
        },
        success:function(result){
            $('#loading).hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It sometimes annoys me that code only answers get accepted. You aren't explaining what happens here, what you've done, how it works. But it has codez! Please consider adding some explanation about what it does and how it works.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha  Well for me like many programmers a short piece of code often is self-explanatory, meaning why explain something two times? At least I read the above code so that after successful AJAX loading just hide the image...

Comment: @jtheman: The process of learning in programming is writing stuff yourself, not asking, getting working solutions, and integrate them into your code.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I do not agree with you. I could as good learn from reading code as from reading an "explanation". On the contrary, mostly an "explanation" in written words leaves me confused but reading code examples gives me real understanding.

Answer (score 3):

You show the spinner (it's called a spinner by the way) when you start the AJAX, and hide it at the `success` function.